# Python: the pandas dataframe function keep thinking the same dataframe has different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2D dataframe and there are some NaN's, so I am using an Imputer function to help me fill those missing values.

When I print:

```
print 'size of X: ', X.shape
```

I get:

```
size of X:  (3373, 36)
```

So it shows that my data frame is 3373 rows by 36 columns.

However, when I try to fit this into the Imputer function right after above print statment:

```
imp = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy='mean', axis=0)
X = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(X), columns=X.columns)
```

I keep getting the Errors:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (35, 3373), indices imply (36, 3373)
```

How is the shape passed values become (35, 3373) when I have checked that it is indeed (36, 3373)? What happened here?

I searched up the Error on Google but other posts do not have same problem as I do, so I couldn't find much help online myself...

I am quite new to Python, and would greatly appreciate any help!

**Note**:

the dtypes for X before transformation looks like:

```
X dtype: 
    Material                   int64
    Plant                      int64
    Material Type              int64
    ...
    MRP group                  int64
    Reorder Point            float64
    dtype: object
```

When I used following code to check if any column is completely null, I didn't get anything printed out. so that should mean I do not have any empty columns in my X, right?

```
for col in X.columns.values:
    if X.ix[:, col].empty:
        print col
```

Comment: What does `X.dtypes` look like before the transformation?

Comment: Hi @MarkDickinson, will update that in my question as well! it's a bit long for a comment.

Comment: From the docs: "When axis=0, columns which only contained missing values at fit are discarded upon transform." Is it possible that at least one of the columns in your dataframe consists entirely of missing values?

Comment: Hi @MarkDickinson, I've added the output for that in the end of my question as well. Seems like I do not have empty columns. Unless my code is incorrectly used!

Comment: I don't think `empty` is what you need: that would be true only for a length-zero Series. Try `X.count()` to see the per-column counts of non-missing values.

Comment: @MarkDickinson okay, something like "for col in X.columns.values:
    if X.ix[:, col].count is 0: print col" right? I still get no output. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: @MarkDickinson but I did find one column that contains only NaN! Thank you so much! but how come my code snippet didnt catch it?